# Check file for string match & a secondary string match followed by altering result line only

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've tried to double `grep` into a `sed` but the `sed` ignores the filtered lines.

I have a file with:

```
    <address domain='0x000' bus='0x71' slot='0x00' function='0x0' />
    <address domain='0x000' bus='0x71' slot='0x00' function='0x1' />
    <address domain='0x000' bus='0x71' slot='0x00' function='0x2' />
    <address type='obo' domain='0x000' bus='0x71' slot='0x0c' function='0x0' />
    <address domain='0x000' bus='0xdt' slot='0x00' function='0x0' />
    <address type='obo' domain='0x000' bus='0x71' slot='0x01' function='0x0' />
    <address domain='0x000' bus='0xdt' slot='0x00' function='0x1' />
```

I'd like to focus on lines with `address domain`, filtered into lines with `function=0x0`...
and finally only changed the `bus IDs`

For example:
If I'm trying to update all `busses` with `0xdt` and function `0x0`, with LABEL_1 the end result would look like...

```
    <address domain='0x000' bus='0x71' slot='0x00' function='0x0' />
    <address domain='0x000' bus='0x71' slot='0x00' function='0x1' />
    <address domain='0x000' bus='0x71' slot='0x00' function='0x2' />
    <address type='obo' domain='0x000' bus='0x71' slot='0x0c' function='0x0' />
    <address domain='0x000' bus='LABEL_1' slot='0x00' function='0x0' />
    <address type='obo' domain='0x000' bus='0x71' slot='0x01' function='0x0' />
    <address domain='0x000' bus='LABEL_1' slot='0x00' function='0x1' />
```

The problem is that it is difficult to focus on specific lines when there are so many lines with duplicate fields. I was able to grep twice into my desired filter, but cannot figure out how to alter the desired string and save to that same file.

Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like a XML file, it can be properly done  with `xmllint` and `XPath`

Get the count of matching nodes

```
xmllint --xpath 'count(//address[@function="0x0" and @bus="0xdt"])' test.xml
```

Change the value of first found node then iterate over the rest using `count`

```
(printf 'cd //address[@function="0x0" and @bus="0xdt"][%d]/@bus\n' 1; echo -e 'set LABEL_1\nsave\nbye') | xmllint --shell test.xml

bus > set LABEL_1
bus > save
bus > bye
```

Make sure to take a backup of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting one line `awk` script:

```
  awk '/address domain=/ && /bus='0xdt'/ && /function='0x0'/{sub("bus='0xdt'","bus='LABEL_1'")}1' input.txt
```

#### Output:

```
<address domain='0x000' bus='0x71' slot='0x00' function='0x0' />
<address domain='0x000' bus='0x71' slot='0x00' function='0x1' />
<address domain='0x000' bus='0x71' slot='0x00' function='0x2' />
<address type='obo' domain='0x000' bus='0x71' slot='0x0c' function='0x0' />
<address domain='0x000' bus='LABEL_1' slot='0x00' function='0x0' />
<address type='obo' domain='0x000' bus='0x71' slot='0x01' function='0x0' />
<address domain='0x000' bus='0xdt' slot='0x00' function='0x1' />
```

Notice output does not match given example!!!

#### `awk` script explanation:

```
/address domain=/       # for a line matching RegExp /address domain=/
&& /bus='0xdt'/         # and matching matching RegExp /bus='0xdt'/
&& /function='0x0'/ {   # and matching matching RegExp /function='0x0'/
  sub("bus='0xdt'","bus='LABEL_1'"); # substitute  RegExp /bus='0xdt'/ with "bus='LABEL_1'"
}
{print} # print each line
```

Comment: for whatever reason all this does for me is `cats` the file but doesn't alter anything.